# How to use filters inside an if condition? - shopify liquid

Tags: if-statement, filter, shopify, liquid

Is it possible to use filters inside an if statement condition ?

I found no way of doing this unless I make a variable that stores the filtered data and then use it inside my condition. Seems odd to me, there must be a better way.

I want to do something like this but I am getting an error:

```
{% if numA | plus:5 >= numB %}
```

I want to avoid doing this:

```
{% assign temp = numA | plus:5 %}
{% if temp >= numB %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to do in not possible in Shopify Liquid. From the official Shopify Liquid issues page

> Parenthesis aren't allowed in Liquid. They can't be used in
> conditionals the way you would use them in a programming language.
>
> Filters are not allowed in conditionals, they will lead to unexpected
> results, at least in Shopify.
>
> The following:
>
> `{% if cart.item_count|times:1 > 5 %}`
>
> Generates this Liquid warning:
>
> `Expected end_of_string but found pipe in "cart.item_count|times:1 > 5"`

So, the only possible solution is what you suggested in your own question.

```
{% assign temp = numA | plus:5 %}
{% if temp >= numB %}
```

[Math filters in IF condition - Liquid](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/362)

Comment: Thank you. This leads to creating a lot of one-time use variables which I was hoping to avoid.